# In What Lies Beneath, what was the shoe with the blood on it all about?

Tags: what-lies-beneath

In *[What Lies Beneath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_Lies_Beneath)*, Claire Spencer (Michelle Pfeiffer) believes her neighbor Mrs. Feur was attacked. She goes over and tries to talk to her neighbors but finds nobody home. She does however find a woman's shoe on the side porch and the shoe has what appears to be blood on it. This leads Claire to believe that Mrs. Feur has been attacked by Mr. Feur.

Later on, Claire even

> confronts Mr. Feur and accuses him of having killed his wife. Mr. Feur simply responds with a look of confusion and then his wife, Mrs. Feur—very much alive—joins him.

However, we're still left wondering, **what was the blood on the shoe all about?** We know that

> nothing sinister/violent was going on at the Feur's home, but

do we ever get an explanation regarding the shoe with the blood?

Comment: Yes, What Lies Beneath [is on-topic](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10127/is-what-lies-beneath-on-topic). :)

Answer (score 2):

The movie deeply sets up its first plotline before revealing that

> M.E.F is Madison Frank, not Mary Fleur.

Several of the elements seem to provide a false trail that are never directly explained:

> Mr. Fleur's need of a shovel, his heavy dufflebag, the box labelled "Mary's Summer Things," and her shoe.

However, the movie does give us some round-about explanations.

> Mary tried to take up gardening, and didn't do it very well.  This directly explains the different soil that Claire found, and somewhat suggests why the shovel is in use.  Later, when Mary and Claire are talking, Mary reveals that her husband brought her things when she was at her mother's.  This is probably the explanation for the box of things (she threw them out after she got back) and the dufflebag.  Mary's shoe presumably fell out of the box, and was stained by some mishap in the past.  Claire is very pointedly cut by a rose thorn around this time, suggesting that the blood might be from a similar injury suffered by Mary.

[The script](http://www.horrorlair.com/scripts/What-Lies-Beneath.pdf) (at pg. 17) also provides another perspective; it only calls for a "dark" stain in that scene, allowing for it to be anything -- old blood from a mishap, or wine, or just dirt.  The visual implication is blood to set the tone, but that's never confirmed.